# Rails 5 Select Not Validating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have an issue where a validation is suddenly not working. The field is a select box, and it's not setting the value.  So when I try to submit the form, it says that `Payee can't be blank`.  This is a 1 to 1 relationship between `Expense` and `Payee`.  What happened? Do you see any issues here?

The field in question.  It's in a helper but I've tried putting it back into the form with no luck.

```
def expense_payee_id_field(f)
  f.select :payee_id, Payee.all.collect { |p| [p.display_name, p.id] }, {  prompt: "Choose Payee"},{class:"fluid ui dropdown"}
end
```

The form:

```
<%= form_for @expense, html: { :class => "ui form segment" }, :remote => true do |f|%>

  <div class="field">

    <%= f.label :date%>
    <div class="ui small input">
      <%= f.date_field :date %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :amount %>
    <div class="ui small input">
      <%= f.text_field :amount %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :check_number %>
    <div class="ui small input">
      <%= f.text_field :check_number %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :payee %>
    <div class="ui input">
      <%= expense_payee_id_field(f)%>
    </div>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit class: "ui blue button" %>
<% end %>
```

My models:
expense.rb

```
class Expense < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :payee
  monetize :amount_cents
  has_many :expense_expense_categories, inverse_of: :expense
  has_many :expense_categories, through: :expense_expense_categories, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :expense_expense_categories,:allow_destroy => true
  validates_associated :expense_expense_categories

  validates :date, presence: true
  validates_numericality_of :amount, presence: true, greater_than: 0
  validates :expense_expense_category_ids, presence: true
  validates_presence_of :payee_id

end
```

payee.rb

```
class Payee < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :expense
  validate :company_or_name


def full_name
  [first_name, last_name].join(" ")
end

def display_name
  if company.blank?
    full_name
  else
    company
  end
end

private
  def company_or_name
    if company.blank? && first_name.blank?
      errors[:base] << "You must specify company or name"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: How does your controller lool like? What params does the application receive?

Comment: do you allow :paee_id in params?

Comment: After double-checking I didn't include :payee_id in params.  I feel dumb now.